# unable to upload image to local server with froala

Tags: php, codeigniter, froala

I'm working on a website using codeigniter and I'm trying to use Froala Editor to upload image in a textarea. it's all working fine until I try to upload the image files to my local folder instead of the default http://i.froala.com/upload

this is my html file:

```
<textarea id="my_editor" name="my_editor" class="editor">
</textarea>
<script>
  $(function() {
    $('.editor').froalaEditor({
      imageUploadURL: "test/froala_upload",
    })
  });
</script>
```

and this is the `froala_upload` function in my `Test` controller file:

```
function froala_upload() {

    // Allowed extentions.
    $allowedExts = array("gif", "jpeg", "jpg", "png", "blob");

    // Get filename.
    $temp = explode(".", $_FILES["file"]["name"]);

    // Get extension.
    $extension = end($temp);

    // Generate new random name.
    $name = sha1(microtime()) . "." . $extension;

    // Save file in the uploads folder.
    move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"], getcwd(). "/assets/review/" . $name);

    // Generate response.
    $response = new StdClass;
    $response->link = "/assets/review/" . $name;
    echo stripslashes(json_encode($response));
}
```

I deliberately omitted the image checking with `finfo` which is used in most documentation about Froala Image Upload because some people say that it could be the problem - yet I'm still unable to upload the image file. and the error message was very helpful: "Something went wrong. Please try again"

I've spent hours scratching my head over this thing. and there is literally no full code solution for this problem on the great wide world of Internet so I can't find out what I'm doing wrong. can anyone help me with this?

Answer (score 2):

As per their documentation you should use this code

```
<script>
  $(function() {
    $('.selector').froalaEditor({
      // Set the image upload URL.
      imageUploadURL: '/your_upload_image_script.php',

      imageUploadParams: {
        id: 'my_editor'
      }
    })
  });
</script>
```

Next you have to create a file named your_upload_image_script.php which should be like

```
<?php
    // Allowed extentions.
    $allowedExts = array("gif", "jpeg", "jpg", "png", "blob");

    // Get filename.
    $temp = explode(".", $_FILES["file"]["name"]);

    // Get extension.
    $extension = end($temp);

    // An image check is being done in the editor but it is best to
    // check that again on the server side.
    // Do not use $_FILES["file"]["type"] as it can be easily forged.
    $finfo = finfo_open(FILEINFO_MIME_TYPE);
    $mime = finfo_file($finfo, $_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"]);

    if ((($mime == "image/gif")
    || ($mime == "image/jpeg")
    || ($mime == "image/pjpeg")
    || ($mime == "image/x-png")
    || ($mime == "image/png"))
    && in_array(strtolower($extension), $allowedExts)) {
        // Generate new random name.
        $name = sha1(microtime()) . "." . $extension;

        // Save file in the uploads folder.
        move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"], getcwd() . "/uploads/" . $name);

        // Generate response.
        $response = new StdClass;
        $response->link = "/uploads/" . $name;
        echo stripslashes(json_encode($response));
    }
?>
```

Comment: Comment passed as [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/39900416/5292302) by [Sina Merajiyan](http://stackoverflow.com/users/5485974/sina-merajiyan) *i've tested your way but it gives me this error "something went wrong. please try again."*

Comment: i have the same problem and i'm using the exact same code when i try "return $_FILES;" i get empty array !!

Comment: Can you do `var_dump($_FILES)` and paste the result here?

Comment: the result is : array(0) { }

Answer (score 0):

It's probably missing `extension` value.

Try the following

```
$finfo = finfo_open(FILEINFO_MIME_TYPE);
$mime = finfo_file($finfo, $_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"]);

$extension = end($temp);
if ($extension == "") {
    list($dummy, $extenstion) = explode("/", $mime);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php

try {
  // File_Route.
  $fileRoute = "/Name_folder/Name";

  $fieldname = "file";

  // Get filename.
  $filename = explode(".", $_FILES[$fieldname]["name"]);

  // Validate uploaded files.
  // Do not use $_FILES["file"]["type"] as it can be easily forged.
  $finfo = finfo_open(FILEINFO_MIME_TYPE);

  // Get temp file name.
  $tmpName = $_FILES[$fieldname]["tmp_name"];

  // Get mime type.
  $mimeType = finfo_file($finfo, $tmpName);

  // Get extension. You must include fileinfo PHP extension.
  $extension = end($filename);

  // Allowed extensions.
  $allowedExts = array("gif", "jpeg", "jpg", "png", "svg", "blob");

  // Allowed mime types.
  $allowedMimeTypes = array("image/gif", "image/jpeg", "image/pjpeg", "image/x-png", "image/png", "image/svg+xml");

  // Validate image.
  if (!in_array(strtolower($mimeType), $allowedMimeTypes) || !in_array(strtolower($extension), $allowedExts)) {
    throw new \Exception("File does not meet the validation.");
  }

  // Generate new random name.
  $name = sha1(microtime()) . "." . $extension;
  $fullNamePath = dirname(__FILE__) . $fileRoute . $name;

  // Check server protocol and load resources accordingly.
  if (isset($_SERVER["HTTPS"]) && $_SERVER["HTTPS"] != "off") {
    $protocol = "https://";
  } else {
    $protocol = "http://";
  }

  // Save file in the uploads folder.
  move_uploaded_file($tmpName, $fullNamePath);

  // Generate response.
  $response = new \StdClass;
  $response->link = $protocol.$_SERVER["HTTP_HOST"].dirname($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]).$fileRoute . $name;

  // Send response.
  echo stripslashes(json_encode($response));

} catch (Exception $e) {
   // Send error response.
   echo $e->getMessage();
   http_response_code(404);
}
?>
```